# Using colorbars in a function

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

For my research report, I've written a custom module which contains, among other things, 2 functions for making images for my report:

`process_mods.py`:

```
def make_image(image, filename, color_map, title):
    '''
    Take as arguments an array, the filename to save as, a color map, and
    a title for the image.
    Produces a publication-quality image of the array, rescaled to Galactic
    coordinates.
    '''
    l_max = 25
    b_max = 15
    xlabel = r'Galactic longitude $\ell$ (deg)'
    ylabel = r'Galactic latitude $b$ (deg)'
    plt.imshow(image, origin='lower',
          extent=[l_max, -l_max, -b_max, b_max],
          cmap = color_map)
    plt.title(title, fontsize = 'small')
    plt.xlabel(xlabel, fontsize = 'small')
    plt.ylabel(ylabel, fontsize = 'small')
    plt.savefig(filename + '.png',
                transparent=False,
                bbox_inches='tight',
                overwrite = True)

def make_image_colorbar(image, filename, color_map, title):
    '''
    Take as arguments an array, the filename to save as, a color map, and
    a title for the image.
    Produces a publication-quality image of the array, rescaled to Galactic
    coordinates, including color bar.
    '''
    l_max = 25
    b_max = 15
    xlabel = r'Galactic longitude $\ell$ (deg)'
    ylabel = r'Galactic latitude $b$ (deg)'
    ax = plt.subplot(111)
    fig =ax.imshow(image, origin='lower',
          extent=[l_max, -l_max, -b_max, b_max],
          cmap = color_map)
    plt.colorbar(fig, fraction = 0.028)
    plt.title(title, fontsize = 'small')
    plt.xlabel(xlabel, fontsize = 'small')
    plt.ylabel(ylabel, fontsize = 'small')
    plt.savefig(filename + '.png',
                transparent=False,
                bbox_inches='tight',
                overwrite = True)
```

The `make_image` function works as intended, and the idea of the `make_image_colorbar` is just to include a color bar with the image.
When I call the `make_image_colorbar` function on two consecutive arrays, the first one looks fine, but the second one has two color bars, one of its own, and one from the first image. Here's the code I'm using to test the module:

```
import process_mods as pm

arr1 = pm.create_random_array(0, 100, 10, 12, 5)
arr2 = pm.create_random_array(0, 100, 10, 12, 10)

pm.make_image(arr1, 'arr1', 'spectral', 'Array1')
pm.make_image_colorbar(arr2, 'arr2', 'spectral', 'Array2')
```

[image]
[image]

This test makes use of

```
def create_random_array(low, high, height, width, seed):
    '''
    Create a random array of floats from lower_limit to upper_limit
    in a height x width matrix
    '''
    np.random.seed(seed)
    random_array = high * np.random.rand(height, width) + low
    return random_array
```

which is another function from `process_mods`, but I don't think that's where the problem lies.

Can anyone see how I can stop the function from printing `arr1`'s colorbar on `arr2`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion comes from not realising what figure/axes you are plotting on. I find that using `matplotlib`'s object oriented interface makes it much clearer which axes you are using.

The changes I would make to your code is to create the figures in your main script and pass them as arguments when calling function defined in `process_mode.py`. This way you can be sure where you are plotting. In addition, you can pass an `ax` argument to `plt.colorbar()` in order to specify which axes it applies to:

```
plt.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
```

`make_image_colorbar` in `process_mods.py` would become:

```
def make_image_colorbar(image, fig, ax, filename, color_map, title):

    l_max = 25
    b_max = 15
    xlabel = r'Galactic longitude $\ell$ (deg)'
    ylabel = r'Galactic latitude $b$ (deg)'

    im = ax.imshow(image, origin='lower',
          extent=[l_max, -l_max, -b_max, b_max],
          cmap = color_map)
    fig.colorbar(im, fraction = 0.028, ax = ax)

    ax.set_title(title, fontsize = 'small')
    ax.set_xlabel(xlabel, fontsize = 'small')
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel, fontsize = 'small')
    fig.savefig(filename + '.png',
                transparent=False,
                bbox_inches='tight',
                overwrite = True)
```

*Note:* I have removed the docstrings just to make this answer easier to read

You *could* (and probably should to be consistent) do the same for `make_image`

You main function would then look like the following.

```
import process_mods as pm

arr1 = pm.create_random_array(0, 100, 10, 12, 5)
arr2 = pm.create_random_array(0, 100, 10, 12, 10)

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()

pm.make_image_colorbar(arr1, fig1, ax1, 'arr1', 'spectral', 'Array1')
pm.make_image_colorbar(arr2, fig2, ax2, 'arr2', 'spectral', 'Array2')

plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]
[image]